# How to use Kotlin ExperimentalUnsignedTypes project wide (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-experimental

I'm trying to use the `@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes` in my AndroidStudio project. It seems I have to put that just about everywhere, so I'd rather set it once project wide.

[The documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-experimental-unsigned-types/index.html) says

> Usages of such API will be reported as warnings unless an explicit
>   opt-in with the UseExperimental annotation, e.g.
>   @UseExperimental(ExperimentalUnsignedTypes::class), or with the
>   -Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes compiler option is given.

Dutifully, I have adjusted my `Preferences>>Other Settings>>Kotlin Compiler`:

[image]

But I still get (lots of) warnings after a clean/make. It was suggested that I also add `-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses` to the same line. But the result is the same. Then I noticed at the top of same preferences pane it says:

[image]

Is this my problem? And if so, where can I adjust my app settings so that these compiler settings are effective?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even with the spelling correction fixed, it still did not compile correctly. I suspect the "...override project settings..." indeed was problematic. However, placing the following in my (project) gradle file did work:

```
   android {
 
       …
 
 tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            // Disable warnings when using unsigned types
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: `Xuse-experimental` has been replaced with `Xopt-in`

Comment: I found that I have to add `::class` after KotlinCompile for this to work. The context of kotlinOptions is shown as "Deprecated", so I think this must be changing (yet again)

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you have `-Xexperimental=...`, not the required `-Xuse-experimental=...`.

Comment: So I do. Confusing, since being that long, I could have sworn I copy-pasted directly from the documentation. Even after fixing that, it still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: However, putting something in the gradle file does seem to work.