# using unsigned types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use [unsigned types](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/unsigned-types.md) in Kotlin. I am using kotlin verison `1.4.32`

I have added the compiler option `-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes` as specified in the documentation.

but I am getting this error: `Type of the constant expression cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies for unsigned types in the classpath`

tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618261/how-to-use-kotlin-experimentalunsignedtypes-project-wide-androidstudio) with no luck.

here is my code

```
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
enum class Status(val value: UByte) {
    None(0x00u)
}
```

I have now inside build.gradle file

```
allprojects {

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes",
                    "-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Sweeper I added the code that I have in Gradle. do you need source code as well?

Comment: I think the question was mostly about the code that utilizes unsigned types ;-) What version of Kotlin do you use? Unsigned types are stable since Kotlin 1.5 and they don't require any compiler flags, etc. anymore - they should *just work*.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use 1.4. I updated the question. please check.

Comment: Do you get this error in IDE only or also when running gradle from the command line?

Comment: from the ide only. I just ran `./gradlew assembleDebug -p app` and it said build successful. weird.

Comment: hold on..`./gradlew assembleDebug ` is failing as well :(

Comment: @RemonShehatta please, provide the complete compiler output and the code mentioned in it. The snippet in your current question seems to be correct.

Comment: I mean, each compiler error in Kotlin relates to a certain location in your code;
e.g. trying to compile `fun main() = println(nothing)` leads to an error in the compiler output `e: something.kt: (1, 22): Unresolved reference: nothing` which means that wrong code starts on line 1, row 22 in the file `something.kt`.

Comment: I have just created a new project in Android Studio with the configurations I mentioned above (Kotlin version and adding compiler arguments) and it gave me the exact error. posting the full error here: `e: /Users/remon.shehata/AndroidStudioProjects/UnsignedTypes/app/src/main/java/com/example/unsignedtypes/MainActivity.kt: (15, 10): Type of the constant expression cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies for unsigned types in the classpath`